# C# SQLite работа с базой

Tags: c#

Не получается выполнить подряд метод записи и удаления. По отдельности работают. Что я не учёл?

```
    SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDB.db; Version=3;");
    public void Connect()
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    public void Insert(string Guid, string Name)
    {
        try
        {
            Connect();
            SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand();
            string query = @"INSERT INTO USERS(Guid,Name) VALUES(@Guid,@Name)";
            command.CommandText = query;
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Guid", Guid));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Name", Name));
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Dispose();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error","Wrong Input!", MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
    public void Delete (string guid)
    {
        try
        {
            Connect();
            SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand();
            string query = "DELETE FROM  USERS WHERE Guid = '"+ guid +"'";
            command.CommandText = query;
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Dispose();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error", "Wrong Input!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: И какую ошибку выводит?

Comment: то есть вы в первом запросе закрываете соединение `connection.Dispose();` а в следующем пытатесь его переоткрыть. Так оно не работает.

Comment: Выполняется  catch. Если // MessageBox ошибок нет. В таблицу пишет а строку не удаляет и  наоборот. Я делаю connection.Dispose() поэтому занята база быть не должна.

Comment: Либо не закрывать соединение, либо создавать соединение на каждый запрос.

Comment: tym32167, спасибо попробую

Comment: Чтобы обратится к кому то, надо писать ник с собачкой, вот так @Malezha

Comment: В запросе Delete тоже используйте параметр. Не используйте конкатенацию строк.

Comment: @Malezha `Выполняется catch` в котором вы даже в `Debug.WriteLine` не выводите состояние ошибки, а просто окно с `Wrong Input!`. `try-catch` не служит для проверки введенных данных, данные нужно проверять до запроса. Не надо так.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dispose()` - это вызов операции разрушения объекта для подготовки к сборке мусора. После вызова `Dispose()` объект `connection` использовать нельзя.

Вместо `Dispose()` используйте `Close()`.

Обработку ошибок так же можно немного улучшить, чтобы знать, что сломалось.

```
SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDB.db; Version=3;");
public void Connect()
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
    }
    catch (SQLiteException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\r\n\r\n" + ex.StackTrace, "Ошибка при подключении!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
public void Insert(string Guid, string Name)
{
    try
    {
        Connect();
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand();
        string query = @"INSERT INTO USERS(Guid,Name) VALUES(@Guid,@Name)";
        command.CommandText = query;
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Guid", Guid));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Name", Name));
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\r\n\r\n" + ex.StackTrace, "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
public void Delete (string guid)
{
    try
    {
        Connect();
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand();
        string query = "DELETE FROM  USERS WHERE Guid = '"+ guid +"'";
        command.CommandText = query;
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\r\n\r\n" + ex.StackTrace, "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```